# Como hacer responsive a estos elementos en resoluciones muy bajas? (estilo iphone 5s)

Tags: css

Bien, mi pagina es responsive hasta cierto punto , pero cuando quiero hacerla responsive para ciertos elementos en ciertas resoluciones bajas, es decir, unos 200px de width, se me deforma.
Lo que busco es que sea adapten (redimensionalizen) esos elementos, la pagina web de donde estan extraidos estos elementos ya es full responsive.

A ver si me pueden ayudar o decirme que hacer..

Dejo unas imagenes de lo que sucede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo aqui el codigo para mayor comodidad: [CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/jmlgomez73/pen/bGgYEpM)

---------**EDICION:**

Probe a hacer :

```css
@media (min-device-width: 50px) and (max-device-width: 321px)  {
  .clock-box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .clock {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

    .clock .hour,
  .hr {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .clock .min,
  .mn {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
  }

  .clock .sec,
  .sc {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .hr::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #ff1744;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .mn::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  
  .sc::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 130px;
    background: #2979ff;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    z-index: 12;
  }

}
```

pero las manecillas no se inmutan

ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, usa `@media` de `CSS`, indicándole el tamaño a trabajar y ya ahí le das los estilos que quieras: `@media (min-device-width: 50px) and (max-device-width: 200px) { ACA TU CSS }`

Comment: lo intente figura mi intento en el code pen... pero nada se me jode todo

Comment: Es porque `.clock` tiene los tamaños asignados en `px`, en el responsive también Tenes que cambiar esos valores.

Comment: Tene en cuenta que en el responsive Tenes que ir cambiando siempre los valores en `px`, porque si no se te desborda todo.

Comment: probe a aplicarlo y para el reloj me sirvi pero para las manecillas no, no responden a lo que pongo en el @media, checkea si puedes el code pen

Comment: Las manecillas también tienen tamaños en `px`, tenes que cambiar todo ir adaptando todo probando tamaños.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/117e0en , como dije lo intente pero no responden a los media

Comment: con el segundo y tercer elemento consegui hacerlo bien ^^ pero tengo ese problema en el reloj y el toogle button

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122787/discussion-between-daniel-and-shockz).

Comment: ya arregle, gracias ^^ pon si quieres todo en una respuesta y te doy "mejor respuesta"

Comment: ya esta todo solucionado , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tú solo estás forzando la falta de responsividad. Vi en tu CSS que le obligas a tomar un `min-width` y `min-height`: estos atributos obligan a tu elemento a no encogerse más de lo que tú mismo le indicas `350px`.

Por consiguiente, se resuelve cambiando los valores mínimos con los `media query`, teniendo en mente el diseño "mobile-first", es decir, se debe ver impecable en pantallas pequeñas sin `media query`: estos serás usados a medida que la pantalla se hace grande para añadir características.